# Sending data from controller to javascript using Linq 500 internal server error mvc2

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

C#

```
public ActionResult SimpleQuery() 
{    
    ClientDataContext dc = new ClientDataContext();
    var userResults = from u in dc.TS_Trucks select u;
    return Json(userResults.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Javascript

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("SimpleQuery")',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

I don't even use the data in the JavaScript, something about the way I'm passing it is probably the problem but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: What's the 500 error say?

Comment: Internal Server Error

Comment: try enabling detailed error messages:

Comment: When you debug this, is there an exception being thrown on the server?  What is that exception?  There's nothing wrong with the JavaScript or with how you're calling the server-side action.  The problem is entirely server-side.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the controller for your url helper. The server error is from trying to locate your action. Try this for the ajax url:

```
'@Url.Action("SimpleQuery", "<ControllerForYourActionHere>")'
```

Comment: This is not correct. You only need to specify the 2nd parameter (the controller name) if the view was generated from a different controller. Secondly, if the url was incorrect, it would return a 404 error, not a 500 error.

Comment: This would've been my suggestion as well, I was unaware of that Stephen, I know on the most recent releases of MVC `URL.Action` is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

**Internal Error usually infers bad URL address.**

In this case, url parameter is not set to right value.

First, you need to check which Router map to this function: SimpleQuery

Then, use that address to fill in url parameter.

Also, I don't think `'@Url.Action("SimpleQuery", "<ControllerForYourActionHere>")'` will work if you put

it in javascript file. It might works in cshtml file.

So, the conclusion is when you are doing frontend programming, use absolute link will be a good idea.

It make sure you hit the right address at the first time.